# Add a new user from a machine not joined with the Active Directory domain

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, domaincontroller

I'm writing a script to add users remotely (via RSAT), from a windows machine that queries the Domain Controller of an Active Directory domain.
To do this, in the New-AdUser command I use the options -Server  and -Credential , where ip is the ip address of the Domain Controller and credentials are the authentication credentials of a user with write permissions.

I state that LDAP connections work because I also perform other operations in the Domain Controller (Read).

The error I get when I try to add a user in the manner described above is this (*x* is a placeholder):

```
+ CategoryInfo: PermissionDenied: (CN = x, DC = x: String) [New-ADUser], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: ActiveDirectoryCmdlet: System.UnauthorizedAccessException, Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands
   .NewADUser
```

I was wondering if the problem is that it is not possible to perform write operations from non-joined machines in the active directory domain.

Comment: No domain handy at the moment, but could be a Kerberos issue due to using the IP of the server. The `-Server` paremeter only supports the following according to the documentation: `Fully qualified directory server name, NetBIOS name, Fully qualified directory server name and port`. Try accessing the server by FQDN or similar instead of IP.

Comment: I need the IP because the DC and the macchine  from where I run the script will not be located in the same network (in production environment)

Comment: Add an entry to the hosts file then

Comment: I was just about to suggest what @DougMaurer said, try adding it to the hosts file, or even better add it to whatever DNS you use.

Comment: I tried with the hosts file but it doesn't work